# Change in contents of folder on branch change in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

Say my working directory is C:\Users\f1 and current branch is master.

If I checkout to another branch (myBranch), how do the contents of C:\Users\f1 get replaced with those of myBranch?

In other words, how does the content of the same folder change with a branch change? Does git delete the current content of the folder (C:\Users\f1) and replace it with that of the new branch?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Executing a branch change? Yes.

Comment: What did you see?

Comment: The files that were in the destination branch replaced those of the source branch

Comment: Does the observation not answer your question?

Comment: Are you asking how is `git checkout` implemented? I suggest you look at the source code: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't know how the change was taking place.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ok thanks. I'll refer to that.

Comment: For me as a git user, I don't care so much about exactly how git does what it does. The important thing is to understand **what** happens when I execute any command, not **how** it does it. If you want to understand the how, you will need to dig into the documentation and source code in a lot of detail.

Comment: AFAIK git when add/deletes files, it also creates/deletes directories if needed. Beyond that, I kinda don't need to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you are in a git repository with `oldbranch` and then do a `git checkout newbranch`:

- git makes note of the changes in files which you have not yet added to the index, as well as changes in the index that you have not committed yet.
- git tries to apply both to `newbranch`.
- If successfull, you end up with `newbranch` checked out, and the changes as before (un-added changes stay un-added; uncommitted changes stay uncommitted).

Note that `git` is not as "daring" during this as in other operations (i.e., this is not a true merge operation). It is rather easy to get the message `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:` and `git` refusing the checkout.

In this case, you can still do the checkout by either removing your changes with `git reset --hard` before the checkout, or by using the stash:

```
git stash
git checkout newbranch
git stash pop
```

Often, the `git stash pop` will just work as expected; and if not, you get the usual merge conflict, which you can resolve manually.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, when you say that 'git tries to apply both to newbranch', does git overwrite the contents of the folder?

Comment: No. To "apply a patch" means to modify a file only with the differences recorded in the patch. These could be things like adding lines, removing lines, changing lines (for example when you add a new method or fix a bug).

Answer (score -1):

When you switch from your master branch to a new branch (myBranch), if you do not specify any remote branch and simply do

> git checkout -b myBranch

Git will just create a new local branch with a copy of the contents of master branch. That is, whatever exists in your master branch will be existing in the same way in your new local branch. 
On the other hand if you create a new local branch tracking from an existing remote branch, like

> git checkout -b myBranch origin/myRemoteBranch

In this case, git will create a local branch with a local copy of the contents of the remote branch specified above. 
As long as your current working branch to be clean, git will allow you to create and switch branches without throwing an error.

So when you switch branches, git basically tracks different remote branches and creates a local copy of it which is your local branch.

At any point of time, you can do

> git remote show origin 
>   To check the tracking of your local branch to remote branches

Hope I cleared your doubt

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be asking about remote branches. Also, you can switch branches without ever adding a remote...

Comment: I did not talk about contents of remote branch, I told about how git tracks contents In local branch, and changes then, which is what the question was intended. And also I did mention that you can create a local branch without a remote branch, pls see above fully

Comment: Ok. It read like you were focusing heavily on remotes. Also (being pedantic here) `git checkout -b myBranch` doesn't copy anything, it creates a new branch pointer to the current commit, and updates HEAD to point to that ref.

Comment: Agree to the git checkout -b part. I intended to convey the same, but your explanation is better put in words there, the pointer part to the HEAD is the better way to put it.